# Theme is changing for only current activity and not others in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to toggle dark/light modes in my app which has multiple activities. The problem is that it changes for only MainActivity and not for all the other activities. How can I change theme of the whole app trough MainActivity? Here's my code:

```
ToggleButton day_night;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    day_night = findViewById(R.id.day_night);

    day_night.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
            else {
                getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try using [setDefaultNightMode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367794/16653700) instead of `setLocalNightMode`. Source:JonasPTFL.

Comment: I tried that but screen just starts blinking and app becomes not responsive

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: You can review my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015914/activity-refreshing-blinking-after-changing-theme-in-android-studio-using-java

Comment: According to [day-night-theme](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/daynight-theme-android-tutorial-example/) you have to set the NightMode before your call to `super` in `onCreate`, so that may be your issue.

Comment: Same again, didn't solve my problem

Comment: Try saving the user`s preference from the `MainActivity` and calling a method in the other activities to set the night mode based on a saved variable.

Comment: No this is nonsense. I have 15+ activities. There has to be another way. Or it's just a bug

Comment: Code should work logically but it doesn't

Comment: If you had one static method you could call the one method in every activity, I think at this point you would save more time doing it that way rather than waiting for an answer. You could always try someone else's suggestions later.